# TableView not showing TableColumns

Tags: java, javafx

I'm doing a JavaFX application and the result of view the data in the table is very inconsistent. My code is the following:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn colName, colSurname, colAge, colID, colTF, colEmail;

private void initializeTable() {
    colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("name"));
    colSurname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("surname"));
    colAge.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("age"));
    colID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("dni")); //why this doesn't work????
    colTF.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("tf")); //why this doesn't work????
    colEmail.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));
    // ...
}
```

And the Person class is:

```
public class Person {
    public SimpleStringProperty name, surname, dni, tf, email;
    public SimpleIntegerProperty age;

    public Person(String name, String surname, int age, String dni, String tf, String email) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.surname = new SimpleStringProperty(surname);
        this.dni = new SimpleStringProperty(dni);
        this.tf = new SimpleStringProperty(tf);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
    }

    public String getName() {return name.get();}
    public String getSurname() {return surname.get();}
    public Integer getAge() {return age.get();}
    public String getDNI() {return dni.get();}
    public String getTF() {return tf.get();}
    public String getEmail() {return email.get();}
}
```

And the table shows **name**, **surname**, **age** and **email**, but NOT **dni** or **tf**. Why???

Comment: Post a [mcve]..

Comment: The code posted in the question is insufficient to diagnose the issue. You'll probably find your answer here though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080442/the-table-cells-are-empty-in-my-tableview-javafx-scenebuilder

Comment: Thank you @fabian, I'll edit the post to put all the code necessary and then the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @fabian to help me find the answer.

The problem was, as @James_D said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080442/the-table-cells-are-empty-in-my-tableview-javafx-scenebuilder)

> The names of your get methods are wrong. According to the PropertyValueFactory documentation, if you pass in a property name of "xyz", the property value factory will first look for a method xyzProperty() belonging to the object in the table row. If it doesn't find that, it will fall back on looking for a method called getXyz() (carefully look at the capitalization there), wrapping the result in a ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.

So the solution is then to change the capitalization in the getters of Person to this:

```
    public String getDni() {return dni.get();}
    public String getTf() {return tf.get();}
```

Comment: good you found the reason for your problem :) Better yet, to _not_ use propertyValueFactory (always bound to break due to typos) but expose the property that's already available in your data